# Como tener un metodo de entrada para ecuaciones matematicas

Tags: javascript, html, web

Estoy haciendo una pagina web en donde los usuarios tienen que ingresar ecuaciones matematicas en un input normal como este (sin editor de texto):

`<input type="text" name="Ecuacion">`

Como le puedo hacer para que los usuarios puedan ingresar las ecuaciones sin tener que hacerlo con una sintaxis complicada, evitar que tengan que poner "sqrt(9" y cosas asi

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Lo que quieres se puede hacer de mil maneras diferentes dependiendo de qué es la experiencia que quieras darle al usuario. Deberías concretar la pregunta más, ¿tienes algo en mente? ¿algún diseño o algo?

Comment: Pues que lo ingresen normal y tu vas buscando los ciertos patrones

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un boton, que automaticamente escriba el simbolo en el input, al cual puedes agregar un evento de keyup, osea cuando levanten la tecla al escribir, y si se encuentra un texto en el input con ese simbolo, se sacará la raiz cuadrada, aqui debes apretar donde dice "raiz cuadrada" y se pondrá su simbolo, luego escribes el numero y te sacará la raiz.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f);
function f(){
 var li = document.getElementById("options").getElementsByTagName("li"),
 eq = document.getElementById("equation"),
 i = document.getElementById("final");
 
 li[0].addEventListener("click", ()=> {
 eq.value += "√";
 });
 var sqrtPattern = /√[0-9]+/ig;
 eq.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
 if(sqrtPattern.test(eq.value)) {
 var find = eq.value.match(sqrtPattern).join("").substr(1);
 i.innerHTML = `La raiz cuadrada de  <b>${find}</b> es <b>: ${Math.sqrt(find).toFixed(2)}</b>`;
 }
 });
}
```

```html
<ul id="options">
<li>Raiz cuadrada</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="equation">


<i id="final"></i>
```